# Graphics Plotly.py

Tags: google-colaboratory, plotly-python

I would like to know how to modify the scale of the axes and change the background color of the graph with plotly.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: Really what I want to do is change the values of the axes so that it is not in [km] but in [au]

Answer (score 1):

You should check : https://plotly.com/python/

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


t = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
x, y, z = np.cos(t), np.sin(t), t

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='markers')])


fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='pink', #Paper background 
              
                  scene=dict(aspectratio=dict(x=6, y=2, z=1), #3d axes ratio

                         xaxis=dict(backgroundcolor='red'),   
                         yaxis=dict(backgroundcolor='purple'), #axes background 
                         zaxis=dict(backgroundcolor='orange')
                         )
              )  

fig.show()
```

[image: example figure]